# Creating a dynamic SQL Search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

facing a small issue i just can't seem to get around.

Im trying to build a dynamic SQL query to return a detailed search from 120 different rows.

So i begin the query with the standard

```
"SELECT * FROM table name"
```

and then id like to add to that multiple

```
"WHERE xxxx = '$xx'"
```

I have a search working absolutely fine if i type it all out into one query using a Var as the search term so

```
"SELECT * FROM table name WHERE xxxx = '$xx'"
```

I can get the results with no issue but as soon as i split the last bit off it just refuses to show the results. I set a

```
if (!result){
$echo "bad request";
}
```

if !result and this is what is showing each time. SO I'm at a loss as to how I can split the tail section off and still have a successful query. if it helps my current failed search query looks like this

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table name " + "$g2query");
```

Many thanks in advance guys.

also..Im aware of the security practices which are still to be implemented but id rather get the searches working before i add anything else.

Thanks guys.

Comment: what do you mean 'last bit'?

Comment: `+` doesn't concatenate in PHP or SQL. What is the expected query?

Comment: Does it actually look like `"SELECT * FROM table name " + "$g2query"` or are you saying that is the concept?

Comment: the tail "WHERE xxxxxx = '$xxx'" , so the default beginning is SELECT * FROM table name" which appears once and i can add as many "tails" as i like, does that help?

Comment: i have  $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table name " + "$g2query"); currently and I have also tried  $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table name '$g2query'"); which also doesn't work?

Comment: I'd put the `where` on the query then use `rtrim` if there are no params added. On param adding do `column = ?` and use a parameterized query.

Comment: That is not right. You need a `.` instead of a `+`. The `+` is used in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table name " + "$g2query");`

the `"SELECT * FROM table name " + "$g2query"` will evaluate to 0, because unlike many other programming languages, a dot(`.`) is used for string concatenation, not a `+`.

Use `"SELECT * FROM table name " . "$g2query"`

There are many other things to consider with this, adding conditions and security measures, but this is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Im aware of security practices as well as the relevant conditions but rather than post up 10 lines of code to explain my issue I reduced it to just one. Its nice of you to understand that and not attempt to make someone feel inferior for no reason. I will happily accept your answer. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

plus sign is used for addition, not to concat string. Use a period instead of a plus.

Just make sure that if you don't have anything for the second part, that you set it an empty string.

```
if(empty($g2query)) $g2query = "";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table name " . "$g2query");;
```

[You're obviously just learning but it's impossible to answer an SQL question on this site without someone saying somehitng about SQL injection.. so I'll just leave this here..](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: He doesn't even need to though. `"SELECT * FROM table name $g2query"` is fine (potentially). More concerning is the variable in the query.

Comment: yep, its unnecessary, i know. he's obviously just learning so let's stick to what's relevant to the question.

Comment: i doubt this guy is going to be writing any enterprise level web apps any time soon anyway.

Comment: It doesn't need to be enterprise or even intentionally malicious. A `'` in the query will break the query.

Comment: its because I have 120 possible query and any could be used in any combination. if there is a better way then I'm all ears being honest, and yes, I'm always learning, as are most developers, I'm just trying to get a new language under my belt as I'm predominantly JAVA and OBJ-C.

Comment: if you already know java and objective c then you should already be well familiar with the concept of data sanitization. @chris85 makes a good point though..

Comment: also. pamblam, I came to ask a question, not get mugged off by some randomer on the internet? your free to leave your comments to yourself as they are not constructive or helpful in anyway as well as just making you sound like a horrible person.

Comment: Got a little self esteem issue there user? I wasnt attacking you. Dont take your self confidence issues out on me..